# get certain Month values in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to get the Values by month date.

[image]

I tried it with this piece of code :

```
DECLARE @IntervalStartDate AS datetime = '{param|SourceDateTime.IntervalStartdateTime:U}'
DECLARE @IntervalEndDate AS datetime   = '{param|SourceDateTime.IntervalEndDateTime:U}'

....WHERE(IntervalDate Between @IntervalStartDateTime AND @IntervalEndDateTime)...
```

But it shows an error:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @mayo, you are trying to achieve the date formatting but are you trying to do that through `SQL` or through `SSRS`? Thanks

Comment: through _SSRS_ and _SQL_ I tried it with this Format **YYYY-MM-DD** but it not works really

Comment: not sure to understand ... for my point of view, if you use `SSRS`, you should be good enough ... no ?

Comment: not really, I used parameters but this is not working

Comment: are you using visual studio ?

Comment: what do you mean "it is not working"?

Comment: The variables you are declaring have different names than those referenced in your WHERE clause...